# Mysql select where polygon contains point always false

Tags: mysql, select, spatial, spatial-query

I have tried various functions like MBRWithin, MBRContains, Intersects, Contains (all of them found in a plenty of posts around here) but no luck yet. This is the simplified query:

```
SELECT * FROM  users
WHERE Intersects( GeomFromText( 'POINT(50 50)' ), GeomFromText( 'POLYGON(0 0, 100 0, 100 100, 0 100, 0 0)' ) );
```

I expected it to evaluate that condition as true (like 1=1) and return all users, however this  did not happen. Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

I am running MySql 5.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    users
WHERE
    MBRContains(
        GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))'),
        GeomFromText('Point(50 50)')) = 1;
```